# hive table does not exist in spark job

Tags: python, hadoop, apache-spark, hive, pyspark

I am using Hive Metastore in EMR.
I am able to query the table manually through HiveSQL or SparkSQL.
But When i use the same table in Spark Job, it says ***Table or view not found***

```
File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 69, in deco pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: 
  u"Table or view not found: `logan_test`.`salary_csv`; line 1 pos 21;
'Aggregate [unresolvedalias(count(1), None)]
+- 'UnresolvedRelation `logan_test`.`salary_csv`
```

Here is my full code

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, HiveContext
from pyspark import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

sc = SparkContext(appName = "test")
sqlContext = SQLContext(sparkContext=sc)
sqlContext.sql("select count(*) from logan_test.salary_csv").show()
print("done..")
```

I submitted my job as below to use hive catalog tables.

`spark-submit test.py --files /usr/lib/hive/conf/hive-site.xml`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're using Spark 2, therefore `SQLContext` and `HiveContext` should be replaced with `SparkSession.sql()` after you `enableHiveSupport()`

And instead of `.sql()`, you can use `SparkSession.table()` to get a DataFrame of the entire table, then follow it with a `count()`, then whatever other queries you want.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.enableHiveSupport().appName("Hive Example").getOrCreate()
salary_csv = spark.table("logan_test.salary_csv")
print(salary_csv.count())
```

Comment: your answer is smart so +1; but i got what i was looking for in another answer.

Comment: what is benifit of using dataframe instead of using sql() ?

Comment: HIveContext is deprecated, you shouldn't rely on it. Sql function returns you a dataframe anyway. The advantage here is your dataframe is a lazy object of the whole table, not just the count of the rows.

Comment: Thanks. So whats the best way to execute an HIVE SQL in spark ? some cases i want to write my own sql and run it not only dataframe.

Comment: `spark.sql("SELECT count(*) from logan_test.salary_csv")` will work fine. The `.sql()` method is just another way to use the DataFrame API... Both compile to a similar execution plan

Comment: great ! just last query, my job fails if there is partition path available. How to disable ``spark.sql.hive.verifyPartitionPath`` in job ?

Comment: It defaults to false. But, you might want to post that as a new question including the error. https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/internal/SQLConf.scala#L391

Comment: ok. here you go..
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47933705/spark-sql-fails-if-there-is-no-specified-partition-path-available

Comment: if i use straight away spark.sql("SELECT count(*) from logan_test.salary_csv") , it says table does nt exist. I believe we need to register the table name before processing ??

Comment: If you didn't enable Hive support, and configure Spark to read the hive site XML, then it's not reading the table from the metastore

Answer (score 2):

You imported `HiveContext` but initialized standard `SQLContext` which doesn't support Hive queries. It should be:

```
sqlContext = HiveContext(sparkContext=sc)
```

Comment: do i still need to use ``sc = SparkContext(appName = "test")`` ?