# SPARK SQL fails if there is no specified partition path available

Tags: python, hadoop, apache-spark, hive, pyspark

I am using Hive Metastore in EMR.  I am able to query the table manually through HiveSQL .
But When i use the same table in Spark Job, it says ***Input path does not exist: s3://***

> Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException: Input path
>   does not exist: s3://....

I have deleted my above partition path in s3://.. but it still works in my Hive without Dropping Partition at table level. but its not working in pyspark anyways

Here is my full code

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, HiveContext
from pyspark import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

sc = SparkContext(appName = "test")
sqlContext = SQLContext(sparkContext=sc)
sqlContext.sql("select count(*) from logan_test.salary_csv").show()
print("done..")
```

I submitted my job as below to use hive catalog tables.

`spark-submit test.py --files /usr/lib/hive/conf/hive-site.xml`

Comment: try with 's3a://' instead of 's3://' in the path

Comment: s3:// works well with other tables and the same table works fine in Hive !

Comment: 1) Stop using SQLContext if you want to talk to Hive. 2) You need to explicitly `enableHiveSupport()` on the SparkSession

Comment: @cricket_007 : Yep ! this is my previous example. i have corrected that in new one  ! thanks

Answer (score 2):

I have had a similar error with HDFS where the Metastore kept a partition for the table, but the directory was missing

Check s3... If it is missing, or you deleted it, you need to run `MSCK REPAIR TABLE` from Hive. Sometimes this doesn't work, and you actually do need a `DROP PARTITION`

That property is false by default, but you set configuration properties by passing a `SparkConf` object to `SparkContext`

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext

conf = SparkConf().setAppName("test").set("spark.sql.hive.verifyPartitionPath", "false"))
sc = SparkContext(conf = conf)
```

Or, the Spark 2 way is using a SparkSession.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder \
...     .appName("test") \
...     .config("spark.sql.hive.verifyPartitionPath", "false") \
...     .enableHiveSupport()
...     .getOrCreate()
```

Comment: i get same error. I have set ``spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Hive Example").config("spark.sql.hive.verifyPartitionPath", "false").enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
``
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: s3://

Comment: Alright, then that property isn't your problem... Your question was just how to configure Spark

Comment: Where did you even read that was the solution for the mentioned error? Can you show the full stacktrace?

Comment: ok. i thought i would need to set that config. but it seems its not.

Comment: my problem is i am to query the table in hive but not through pyspark .. any idea what would be the issue ? The path mentioned in the error log is partition path which i deleted

Comment: I have modified my question as ``I have deleted my above partition path in s3://.. but it still works in my Hive without Dropping Partition at table level. but its not working in pyspark anyways`` please have a look. sorry for the confusion

Comment: I have updated my answer to reflect the fact you deleted the path

Comment: I am facing the similar issue ? Were you able to resolve this ?

Comment: My answer resolved it for me, probably, otherwise I wouldn't have answered. Considering this was 9 months ago, I don't really remember, though