# Spark SQL Fails when hive partition is missing

Tags: apache-spark, hive, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a table which has some missing partions. When I call it on hive it works fine

```
SELECT *
  FROM my_table
```

but when call it from pyspark (v. 2.3.0) it fails with message `Input path does not exist: hdfs://path/to/partition`. The spark code I am running is just naive:

```
spark = ( SparkSession
         .builder
         .appName("prueba1")
         .master("yarn")
         .config("spark.sql.hive.verifyPartitionPath", "false")
         .enableHiveSupport()
         .getOrCreate())

spark.table('some_schema.my_table').show(10)
```

the `config("spark.sql.hive.verifyPartitionPath", "false")` has been proposed is 
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47933705/spark-sql-fails-if-there-is-no-specified-partition-path-available) question but seems to not work fine for me

Is there any way I can configure SparkSession so I can get rid of these. I am afraid that in the future more partitions will miss, so a hardcode solution is not possible

Comment: Is your table external ? If so , can you try msck repair on the hive table thru hive or alter table add the partitions

Answer (score 3):

This error occurs when partitioned data dropped from HDFS i.e not using **Hive commands** to drop the partition.

If the data dropped from **HDFS directly** Hive **doesn't know about the dropped the partition**, when we query hive table it still looks for the directory and the directory doesn't exists in HDFS it results `file not found exception`.

To fix this issue we need to drop the partition associated with the directory in Hive table also by using

```
alter table <db_name>.<table_name> drop partition(<partition_col_name>=<partition_value>);
```

Then hive drops the partition from the metadata this is the only way to drop the metadata from the hive table if we dropped the partition directory from HDFS.

**msck repair table**  `doesn't drop the partitions` instead **only adds** the **new partitions** if the new partition got added into HDFS.

The `correct way` to avoid these kind of issues in future **drop the partitions by using Hive [drop partition](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-DropPartitions) commands.**

Comment: Ok, but the point is that I'm not Hive's owner and I am not authorize to create | drop | alter | etc...  any table. Just querying. I can talk with them and ask to clean the partitions and try to prevent such a problem in the future, but I guess no one will hear my petition, so I am trying to look for a solution from Spark better than from hive. Thank you anyway for your answer ;)

Comment: @LuisMorillo Another option of loading data is from **HDFS** without using Hive table to get the data for the partition. refer to this link regards for more details https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=load#pyspark.sql.DataFrameReader.load

Comment: @Shu, We do not have control over hive table for now. Is there any workaround for this, so that spark can gracefully handle this instead of throwing an exception?

Answer (score 1):

Does the other way around, `.config("spark.sql.hive.verifyPartitionPath", "true")` work for you? I have just managed to load data using spark-sql with this setting, while one of the partition paths from Hive was empty, and partition still existed in Hive metastore. Though there are caveats - it seems it takes significantly more time to load data compared to when this setting it set to false.